# Give selection box full with beside icon

Tags: html, css

I have a selection box and an icon inside a container like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <select name="select" style="width:100%">
  <option>Girl</option>
  <option>Boy</option>
  </select>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</div>
```

[image]

I want that the selection box has the full width of the container minus the length of the icon, so that they are next to each other.

I was thinking about measuring the pixel width of the icon and setting that as the `margin-right` of the select box. But that does not seem to work with `width:100%` and I am also not sure if the pixel width of the icon will be the same on all devices.

How can I selection box as wide as possible while on one line with the icon?

Here is a [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a321bspn/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for this. You can assign the parent container to display as a flexbox using `display:flex;`. Furthermore you can use the css property `flex`, which is shorthand for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` combined. Setting this to a value of `1`, tells the element to consume all the "empty" horizontal spacing.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

select{
  flex: 1;
}

i{
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

select{
  flex: 1;
}

i{
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <select name="select">
    <option>Girl</option>
    <option>Boy</option>
  </select>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</div>
```

You can find additional information on flexbox [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/an-animated-guide-to-flexbox-d280cf6afc35)

Comment: what is `select{
  flex: 1;
}` doing?

Answer (score 2):

**Flexbox**

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
}

select {
  flex: 1; /* be as wide as possible */
}

i {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <select name="select">
    <option>Girl</option>
    <option>Boy</option>
  </select>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</div>
```

**CSS-Grid**

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  /* first column will be as wide as possible */
}

i {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <select name="select">
    <option>Girl</option>
    <option>Boy</option>
  </select>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flex layout could solve your problem, please check the following code:

```html
<style>
  .container {
      border:1px solid;
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:row;
  }
  select{
    width: 100%;  
  }
  i{
    font-size: 1em;
  }
</style>
<div class="container">
  <select name="select">
  <option>Girl</option>
  <option>Boy</option>
  </select>
  <i class="fa fa-star">icon</i>
</div>
```

Also more requirement, check this link:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp